# Get same data from mysql before updated despite of using async.waterfall

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have 2 tasks:

- update data: `updateTask`
- fetch data after updated: `fetchTask`

try both:

```js
async.waterfall([updateTask, fetchTask], function(err, result){...})
```

or

```js
async.parallel([updateTask], function(err){
   async.parallel([fetchTask], function(err, result){...})
})
```

but `result` still same data before `updateTask` executed.

I have 2 env (dev and staging), the one is always worked and the other one is not.

Comment: Just check your `updateTask ` is success or not.

Comment: @hoangdv always success

Comment: `waterfall ` is true way for your case, check again what has been call in the final `next` function, `next(null, value_need_to_check)`